# Using only PIP for installing spacy model en_core_web_sm

Tags: python, pip, spacy

Is there a way to install `en_core_web_sm` just by using pip (assuming I already have spacy installed)

From the spacy documentation , I know it's to be done using `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

I also know one can do it using conda with `conda install spacy-model-en_core_web_sm`

But I am unable to find a way using just pip. I am restricted to using pip in the project.

Edit: Using pip install <model's github link/local link to .whl> is not an option because installation from github isn't allowed. We store all packages and models in an internal repo and en_core_web_sm  is indeed present there but I don't know how to fetch with something simple like `pip install spacy-model-en_core_web_sm` without specifying the local/githublink

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the "Downloading models" section of their github:

> To increase transparency and make it easier to use spaCy with your own
> models, all data is now available as direct downloads, organised in
> individual releases. spaCy 1.7 also supports installing and loading
> models as Python packages. You can now choose how and where you want
> to keep the data files, and set up "shortcut links" to load models by
> name from within spaCy.

```
# pip install .whl or .tar.gz archive from path or URL
pip install /Users/you/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz
pip install /Users/you/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

It's worth noting running `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` really just launches pip in a subprocess in this case.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add that pip install <github link> is blocked inside our org. We store everything in our internal repo and en_core_web_sm is present as well. The only problem is that I don't know how to get this with pip, but I do know you can get it with `conda install spacy-model-en_core_web_sm` I basically don't want to mention the local / repo link to the model while installation. I am looking for something simple like the conda installation where conda fetches the model from the repo

Comment: Is there a way to see what the command for the pip sub process is ?