Using spaCy in Microsoft Fabric
Our organisation is trailing MS Fabric, and i'm trying out Notebooks. I've managed to create an environment and brought in NLTK and spaCy libraries. However, typically when you use spaCy you also import a corpus to work with such as the small corpus for English: en_core_web_sm
As Fabric is a 'complete solution' and I don't have access to pip install / terminal or anything like that (our organisation locks this down) i've no clue how to initialise spaCy to start with:
# Initialize spaCy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

I have to think it's possible, as otherwise you couldn't use the library at all?
I get the predictable error:
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Any ideas?

As I am not familiar with Microsoft Fabric I am not sure how you installed SpaCy and NLTK in the first place, but you can take that same way to install the model if just the python command is unavailable. Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230761/18189622.

If you are in a fresh new environment you need first to download the en_core_web_sm, only then you can load it. Since you are in a Notebook, execute the following in the first cell:
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

Different Notebooks version may require a different charachter to execute commands in the local terminal. Like %

To install the model you can use the pip command below:
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

or refer the docs: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models
